# Оптимальная выборка из 3-х массивов

Tags: массивы, php, foreach

Есть три простых массива - $deals_contacts, $deals и $contacts

```
    deals:
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25386407
            [name] => school_test_deal_1
            [date_create] => 2014-08-04 17:47:00
            [price] => 5000
            [status] => 9376319
            [contacts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => school_test_contact_1
                    [1] => school_test_contact_2
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25386435
            [name] => school_test_deal_2
            [date_create] => 2014-08-04 19:15:00
            [price] => 10000
            [status] => 9376319
            [contacts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => school_test_contact_1
                )
        )
итд

contacts:
 [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39891724
            [name] => school_test_contact_1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39901572
            [name] => school_test_contact_2
        )
итд

deals_contacts:
[0] => Array
(
    [id] => 39891724
    [name] => school_test_contact_1
)

[1] => Array
(
    [id] => 39901572
    [name] => Test_company_1
)
итд
```

В них содержится выборка из базы данных (отношение deals и contacts - многие ко многим, а $deals_contacts - была соединительная таблица)
Задача - добавить каждому элементу массива deals соответствующий contact (получается используя соединительный массив deals_contacts)

У меня получилось три цикла foreach, это настораживает

```
foreach ($deals_contacts as $relation) {
        foreach($deals as &$deal) {
            if ($deal[id] == $relation[ID_DEAL] ) {
                foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
                    if ($contact[id] == $relation[id]) {
                        $deal[contacts][] = $contact[name];
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Можно ли сделать это оптимальнее?

Comment: @silent-box, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @silent-box, есть ли возможность изменить запросы и просто добавить джойн?

Comment: Эти таблицы массивы потом используются в других местах кода, боюсь что надо работать именно с ними